# org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException, MySQL, OpenJPA, Geronimo

Tags: mysql, jpa, ejb, openjpa, geronimo

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error (full stack trace below):

> Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = innodb' at line 1** {stmnt 763763032 CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER (admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), user_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)) TYPE = innodb} [code=1064, state=42000]*

I've got a web app with `MySQL 5.5.11` and `openJPA 1.2.2` and `Geronimo 2.2.1 with Tomcat 6`.  I'm able to depoly the `.ear` fine.  But when I submit my form to persist a `Admin @Entity`, I get the following error above.

Also, I'm using `tranql-connector-mysql-local-1.5.rar` (from the Geronimo repository) as my connector.

### persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="AReyesPersistUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>AReyesMySql</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.areyes.entity.Admin</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### Admin @Entity

```
@Entity
@Table (name="ADMIN_USER")
public class Admin implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name="admin_id")private long id;
    @Column (name="user_name")private String userName;
    @Column (name="first_name")private String firstName;
    @Column (name="last_name")private String lastName;
```

...followed by getters/setters

### Stack trace

```
2011-06-30 23:15:52,203 ERROR [[AddAdmin]] Servlet.service() for servlet AddAdmin threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = innodb' at line 1 {stmnt 1243851750 CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER (admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), user_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)) TYPE = innodb} [code=1064, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:359)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:287)
    at $Proxy65.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.areyes.servlet.AddAdmin.doPost(AddAdmin.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:420)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:396)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:214)
    at org.apache.geronimo.pool.ThreadPool$ContextClassLoaderRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:344)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = innodb' at line 1 {stmnt 1243851750 CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER (admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), user_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)) TYPE = innodb} [code=1064, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:553)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:453)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at org.apache.geronimo.persistence.CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.createEntityManager(CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.java:74)
    at org.apache.geronimo.persistence.CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.getEntityManager(CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.java:55)
    at org.apache.geronimo.persistence.CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.persist(CMPEntityManagerTxScoped.java:81)
    at com.areyes.session.AdminManager.create(AdminManager.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:122)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:174)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:217)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:282)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = innodb' at line 1 {stmnt 1243851750 CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER (admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), user_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)) TYPE = innodb} [code=1064, state=42000]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:192)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:57)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:762)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.executeSQL(SchemaTool.java:1191)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.createTable(SchemaTool.java:949)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.add(SchemaTool.java:526)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.add(SchemaTool.java:344)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaTool.run(SchemaTool.java:321)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.record(MappingTool.java:501)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: When I manually create the table, I'm able to insert my Admin @Entity as expected.  But I still don't know why openJPA won't create my table.  Insen't the openjpa.jdbc.SychronizedMappings property set to a value of 'buildSchema' suppose to create my tables?

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually connecting to MySQL and not a Derby DB?

Comment: If I'm able to insert to tables in MySQL using my web app.  So I would say I'm connecting to MySQL.  Seems like my prob is that I'm not able to create the tables base off my entities.

Comment: Have you tried to use the SQL that is shown in the exception? CREATE TABLE ADMIN_USER (admin_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), user_name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)) TYPE = innodb

Comment: The SQL from the exception works if I remove 'TYPE = innodb'.  If I leave 'TYPE = innodb' in the command I get the following error: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE' at line 1.  Also, I have to fully qualify the table witht the schema name.  Other than that, the exact SQL from the exception works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging, this is a [bug that has already been fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1530). The root issue is that MySQL changed the table_option 'type' to 'engine' in the 5.1ish time frame.

Either you can move to a newer level of OpenJPA(1.3.x, 2.0.x, etc), or don't use OpenJPA to create your tables.